# calculating relative position in array in c

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of integers.  The integers can be positive or negative, and there can be duplicates.
I sort the array, low to high, using qsort.

```
int myArray[] = { -4, -2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 9, 14, 17, 24 };
```

I then want to find the relative position of one of the integers (X) in the array, so I divide the position (Y) of the integer by the size of the array (S), and subtract .5 from the result, so that the relative position is expressed on a scale from -.50 to .50.

```
double position = Y/S - .50;
```

I want the lowest value in the array (in this case, -4) to be -.50, and the highest value (in this case, 24)  to be .50?  This works for the lowest value in the array, but not the highest:

```
double lowPosition = 0/12 - .50;  // lowPosition = -.50 double

highPosition = 11/12 - .50;  // highPosition = .42
```

Two questions:

1. What is the correct way to calculate this so I end up with the low value equal to -.5 and the high value = .5?
2. How can I accurately calculate the relative position of a value when there are duplicates?  Should I eliminate the duplicates and then use the same calculation (position/size - .5)?

Comment: Make sure you do a float division & not integer division. ;)

Comment: Did u try to implement it?

Comment: What is your solution for duplicates? For example, what output do you want for array [1, 1, 1, 1]?

Comment: How about `Y/(S-1) - 0.5`? It would range from -0.5 to +0.5. It would fail for `S==1` & it should, because for `S==1`, both `+/-0.5` are equally correct values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is the correct way to calculate this so I end up with the low value equal to -.5 and the high value = .5?

Since the highest position in an array is at `S - 1` (where `S` is the size of the array), you'll have to divide by `S - 1` instead of `S`.
Make sure to have a special case for arrays of size `1`, or you'll get a division by `0`.

> 2) How can I accurately calculate the relative position of a value when there are duplicates? Should I eliminate the duplicates and then use the same calculation (position/size - .5)?

It depends what relative positions you want to get. But removing duplicates sounds like a reasonable approach.